# Cell-wise summation of tables in a linux shell script

Tags: bash, awk, text-files

I have a set of tables in the following format:

```
1000 3 0 15 14
2000 3 0 7 13
3000 2 3 14 12
4000 3 1 11 14
5000 1 1 9 14
6000 3 1 13 11
7000 3 0 10 15
```

They are in simple text files.

I want to merge these files into a new table in the same format, where each cell (X,Y) is the sum of all cells (X,Y) from the original set of tables. One slightly complicating factor is that the numbers from the first column should not be summed, since these are labels.

I suspect this can be done with AWK, but I'm not particularly versed in this language and can't find a solution on the web. If someone suggests another tool, that's also fine.

I want to do this from a bash shell script.

Comment: Please provide an example of your expected output.

Comment: do you want to sum all the columns from each file or each cell belonging to same label from each file? does this make sense? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
    for (i=2;i<=NF; i++)
        a[$1,i]+=$i
    b[$1]=$1
    if (NF>maxNF) maxNF=NF
}

END {
    n=asort(b,c)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        printf "%s ", b[c[i]]
        for (j=2;j<=maxNF;j++) {
            printf "%d ", a[c[i],j]
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

Run it like this:

```
./sumcell.awk table1 table2 table3
```

or

```
./sumcell.awk table*
```

The output using your example input twice would look like this:

```
$ ./sumcell.awk table1 table1
1000 6 0 30 28
2000 6 0 14 26
3000 4 6 28 24
4000 6 2 22 28
5000 2 2 18 28
6000 6 2 26 22
7000 6 0 20 30
```

Comment: do u use blockquotes? my answer looks... pityful.

Comment: @jgr: no, use the `010101` button or indent your code using four spaces. I edited your post, take a look at what I did.

Answer (score 1):

Sum each line, presuming at least one numeric column on each line.

```
while read line ; do
    label=($line)
    printf ${label[0]}' ' ;
    expr $(
        printf "${label[1]}"
        for c in "${label[@]:2}" ; do
            printf ' + '$c
        done 
    )
done < table
```

EDIT: Of course I didn't see the comment about combining based on the label, so this is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -anE'$h{$F[0]}[$_]+=$F[$_]for 1..4}{say$_,"@{$h{$_}}"for sort{$a<=>$b}keys%h' file_1 file_2
```